# What's the best way to handle "search" in a REST API? What about Sphinx?

Tags: php, api, search, rest, sphinx

When there are a lot of results, and they are always changing - what's the best way to handle "search" in a REST API?

Background:
I have a community-service website that lists free local items for churches, community groups, or struggling families - so we have a lot of listings usually from donors, or scanned on other websites. Ideally a REST API for this website would call up listings based on certain criteria that we outline in the methods - But there can be a lot of results, and they're always changing!

Something like Sphinx Search?
We allow distance searches (all listings are geo-tagged) - I've seen that Sphinx Search has a native (fast!) distance-search function, and also caches searches - is it typical to include some type of search engine in a REST API? I'm guessing it would be an interface between the API and another application on the server like Sphinx...

Comment: you missed one point, `the data update frequently `

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your question.  Your main concern seems to be that the data is changing frequently, but that is the case with many search engines.
Consider StackOverflow, they allow you to retrieve a search result by using the following:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo
```

If you call it a few minutes later you will get a different result.  What technology you use behind the scenes to do the search really does not affect the exposed resources.  How long you cache those results depends on how long you believe those results will be valid for and how likely someone else is to make the exact same request.

I think I must be missing something here.